# Selecting random value from a table with multiple entries to insert into another table in hive

Tags: select, random, hive

[image]

I need to select random values from above table where when there are multiple values (exampl:- of 3333,4444,6666) . Currently I am using below code which is biased in the final result.

```
insert into com_n3
select distinct number,min(district)
from com_n2
```

result will give more numbers with value "A" as the district. I need a unbiased random way to select from multiple entries.

Comment: sorry.modification done

Comment: how many random values you want from this table, if you want all that's not random :)

Comment: I just need one . for example for number "4444" i just need one from "B","A" or "G"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get some random records using following query.

```
select number, district 
from 
    (
        select *,  row_number() over (partition by number order rand()) as rank 
        from 
            temp.com_n2
    ) a  
where a.rank=1
```